# Cannot deploy my simple servlet on Jetty, but it works on GlassFish

Tags: servlets, deployment, jetty, war

I am trying to deploy my very simple webapp on Jetty, but I cannot get it to work. The same WAR file works perfectly under GlassFish ans JBoss. It is a simple webservice and does not contain any EJB´s or simillar.

I have placed the WAR file in /usr/share/jetty/webapps/ folder and I try to access it in the same way as when it is deployed on GlassFish (`http://localhost:8080/MySimpleServer/rest/getName`).

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <finalName>MySimpleServer</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Here is the web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>MySimpleServer</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>MySimpleServer</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: What's the full name of the WAR file?

Comment: MySimpleServer.war is the name of the WAR file. I am just learning how to deploy this simple WAR on different platforms.

Comment: Could it be something simple like case sensitivity?  What if you try to access *localhost:8080/mysimpleserver*?  Do you see any errors in the Jetty logs?